# Partitioning the first-stage feasibility set

Tags: optimization, stochastic-calculus, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am working on a two-stage stochastic problem, and I must know how we can partition the first-stage feasibility set of our problem using the optimality cuts (in L-shaped method). Is there any advice on that? Thanks